# Strange issue of column does not exist in Sync Framework 2.1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I have been facing a strange problem in MS Sync Fx 2.1.

I have around 50 tables to be synced between client and central server. Out of 50 tables, 20 tables I have to apply filter using 2 columns.

Now when I try to provision the server DB for the filter columns, it's giving me error saying the filter columns does not exists in the table.

But when I check the database for these columns they exists in all the tables.

Comment: Can you post the provisioning code and the error?

Comment: JuneT - I got it resolved. MS Sync Fx is case sensitive.the column names needs to be in the same case as they appear in the table.

Comment: Afaik, sync fx is not case sensitive. What's your DB's collation settings?

Comment: My DB Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS